# Installed activeadmin messing with my routes incompatibility issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I just ran `rails g active_admin:install`, the standard is it generated and installed a bunch of files on my rails application. When I run that I am getting this

```
/Users/judyngai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:409:in `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'admin_root'  (ArgumentError)
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
```

this is now what my routes look like

```
Lintong::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  #get 'signup', to: 'students#signup'


  root :to => 'students#signup'

  resources :students #may not be necessary 

  devise_for :students
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

I can not do `rails s`

I am getting this , the same error. I am not so familiar with routes and will be reading up on it. I hope someone can explain to me what I did wrong and how to solve this.

```
/Users/judyngai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:409:in `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'admin_root'  (ArgumentError)
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
```

Comment: You have `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)` in your routes twice.  remove the entry under the students resource map ??

Comment: @trh yes I can do rails s (after removing the extra route) and it yells that I need to run the migration, but if I do this did activeadmin fully generated all the files that it need?

Comment: I found this solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242897/installing-active-admin-and-getting-an-argumenterror

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're most of the way there - just double check your steps and your output

From the beginning and you can see where you are in the process.

Add to your gemfile

```
  gem 'activeadmin'
```

Install

```
 bundle install
```

Run the install generator

```
rails generate active_admin:install
```

Running that should spit out data telling you what files were created in your app.  It will look something like :

```
      invoke  devise
generate    No need to install devise, already done.
  invoke    active_record
  create      db/migrate/20130829160843_devise_create_admin_users.rb
  create      app/models/admin_user.rb
  invoke      rspec
  create        spec/models/admin_user_spec.rb
  invoke        factory_girl
  create          spec/factories/admin_users.rb
  insert      app/models/admin_user.rb
   route    devise_for :admin_users
    gsub    app/models/admin_user.rb
    gsub    config/routes.rb
  insert    db/migrate/20130829160843_devise_create_admin_users.rb
  create  config/initializers/active_admin.rb
  create  app/admin
  create  app/admin/dashboard.rb
  create  app/admin/admin_user.rb
  insert  config/routes.rb
generate  active_admin:assets
  create  app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss
  create  db/migrate/20130829160852_create_admin_notes.rb
  create  db/migrate/20130829160853_move_admin_notes_to_comments.rb
```

As longs as you saw that string, you have the files you need to get started.  At this point you should have only one entry in your routes for ActiveAdmin

Now migrate

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Restart your server and you should be able to log in.

Now set up your models

```
rails generate active_admin:resource ModelNameHere
```

Answer (score 0):

In your routes file you have added `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)` twice
try removing the extra one and run it again

It might be the reason

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Fixed it by restarting my server after migrating the active admin changes.